# Mac OS Sierra virtualenv (python 2.7) pip install mysqlclient error

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, pip, homebrew, macos-sierra

On Mac OS Sierra, created virtualenv using python2.7 and trying to install mysqlclient to use Django w/ MySQL. I installed MySQL 5.6 via homebrew. Running "pip install mysqlclient" gives these errors:

```
Running setup.py bdist_wheel for mysqlclient ... error
...
 13 warnings generated.
  cc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -Wl,-F. build/temp.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/_mysql.o -L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql56/5.6.32/lib -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/_mysql.so
  ld: library not found for -lssl
  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

---

```
  Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
Command "...env2.7/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/nm/mqfwjt115q7g0lpvnx7sylwm0000gn/T/pip-build-tJmAVS/mysqlclient/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/nm/mqfwjt115q7g0lpvnx7sylwm0000gn/T/pip-xVuIu1-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers .../env2.7/include/site/python2.7/mysqlclient" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/nm/mqfwjt115q7g0lpvnx7sylwm0000gn/T/pip-build-tJmAVS/mysqlclient/
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The answer was installing dev tools using:

`xcode-select --install`

Comment: Worked for me, too. I'm still on OS X El Capitan, but had the same error message.

Answer (score 9):

In my case I needed to do two steps:

```
xcode-select --install
```

as @howevilweare says AND also pip install with the brew installed openssl using an env command:

```
env LDFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" pip install mysqlclient
```

Comment: As far as I can tell this is the only way to get this to work on macOS Sierra with Homebrew's openSSL.