# "OSError: mysql_config not found" when trying to "pip install mysqlclient" - Django

Tags: pip, virtualenv, mysql-python, macos-high-sierra

I'm relatively new to Django, and Web Development in general.

I am trying to

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

in my

```
virtualenv -p python3
```

to hook up Django 2.0 to mySQL. However, I'm getting this error:

```
Collecting mysqlclient
Using cached mysqlclient-1.3.12.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
/bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/private/var/folders/43/md5vpqrx0mx8627sq04slbz00000gn/T/pip-build-l8ea3vja/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
    metadata, options = get_config()
  File "/private/var/folders/43/md5vpqrx0mx8627sq04slbz00000gn/T/pip-build-l8ea3vja/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 44, in get_config
    libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
  File "/private/var/folders/43/md5vpqrx0mx8627sq04slbz00000gn/T/pip-build-l8ea3vja/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 26, in mysql_config
    raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
OSError: mysql_config not found

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/43/md5vpqrx0mx8627sq04slbz00000gn/T/pip-build-l8ea3vja/mysqlclient/
```

I have looked around for answers for hours, and yes, I have checked out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35190465/virtualenvpython3-4-pip-install-mysqlclient-error) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40348571/mac-os-sierra-virtualenv-python-2-7-pip-install-mysqlclient-error) but nothing seems to be working.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You've linked to other questions, but you haven't said which OS you are on, or what happened when you ran the suggested commands.

Comment: @Alasdair I'm running MacOS High Sierra (Version 10.13.1). When I run: 'sudo apt-get install python-dev python3-dev' i get: 'sudo: apt-get: command not found' for example

Comment: `apt-get` is a package manager used by some linux distributions like Ubuntu and Debian. It doesn't make sense to run those commands on MacOS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to install mysqlclient using pip3 on MacOS sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41911170/unable-to-install-mysqlclient-using-pip3-on-macos-sierra)

Comment: I have checked out the thread claimed to be duplicate above, and i when I run 'brew install mysql-connector-c', I get the error: '-bash: brew: command not found'

Comment: `brew` is a command from [homebrew](https://brew.sh/), which is a package manager for MacOS. You'll need to install homebrew if you want to use it.

Comment: If you're new to Django, are you sure you need MySQL at this point. If you're just learning, then it's easier to use sqlite.

Answer (score 22):

the python package "mysqlclient" is depended on C system library to drive mysql connect，if you on ubuntu 16.4， just do as below：

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
sudo pip install mysqlclient
```

Comment: MySQLdb is a C extension so depend on C lang library. You can use pymysql only instead of MySQLdb, just do a commond as below : sudo pip install pymysql

Comment: The first command was all I needed to install correctly for a Plotly Dash app with conda env.

Answer (score 3):

If you get `OSError: mysql_config not found` when installing the `mysqlclient` Python package in macOS, then just do:

```
brew install mysql-client
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/mysql-client/bin:$PATH"
```

and retry.

Answer (score 2):

You should start with cloning the mysqlclient repo:

```
git clone https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python
```

Then you will have to get `mysql-connector-c`. You can get it by doing:

```
brew install mysql-connector-c
```

Then open `/usr/local/bin/mysql_config` in a text editor.

From the Github [issue](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python/issues/169):

There are lines in mysql_config like following:

```
# Create options 
libs="-L$pkglibdir"
libs="$libs -l "
```

It should be:

```
#Create options 
libs="-L$pkglibdir"
libs="$libs -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto"
```

Save that file and change back to the directory where you downloaded the repo. Now open `site.cfg` file.
uncomment the line (remove the #)

```
#mysql_config = /usr/local/bin/mysql_config
```

Save that and run:

```
python3 setup.py install
```

Comment: Thanks for this. When I run: 'brew install mysql-connector-c', I get the error: '-bash: brew: command not found'

Comment: Hi Pranjal, Ok so I've downloaded Homebrew, successfully run 'brew install mysql-connector-c', succesfully opened '/usr/local/bin/mysql_config' in my text editor, but now I am unsure how to edit the file to: libs="-L$pkglibdir"
libs="$libs -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto" Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

For CentOS here's what made it work for me:

```
yum install gcc mysql-devel openssl-devel

#Install library explicitly, otherwise the python3 setup.py install will fail
pip3 install "mysqlclient==2.0.3" --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-L/usr/lib64/mysql/"
```

Comment: Works for Almalinux 8.7 as well on Python 3.9 -- no need to add the global options in my case