# mysqlclient==1.3.12 errorring on pip install

Tags: python, mysql

I'm running python 3.6.8 on a Ubuntu 18.04 VPS and trying to install a Django project with mysqlclient==1.3.12.

When I run `pip install -r requirements.txt` (in the virtual environment), I'm getting this error

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /var/www/authenticjobs/env/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-uzc9j1dl/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-uzc9j1dl/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-uzc9j1dl/mysqlclient/
    Complete output (10 lines):
    /bin/sh: 1: mysql_config: not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-uzc9j1dl/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-uzc9j1dl/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 44, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
      File "/tmp/pip-install-uzc9j1dl/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 26, in mysql_config
        raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
    OSError: mysql_config not found
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I know MySQL is install because when I run `systemctl status mysql.service`, I get

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2019-09-11 10:25:22 UTC; 4min 3s ago
 Main PID: 9092 (mysqld)
    Tasks: 28 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
           └─9092 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql\_config not found when installing mysqldb python interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475223/mysql-config-not-found-when-installing-mysqldb-python-interface)

Comment: also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47870628/oserror-mysql-config-not-found-when-trying-to-pip-install-mysqlclient-dja

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must install mysql client tools/libraries. You have the sever installed not the client.

Comment: fyi, the package on ubuntu 18 on my scenario was : `libmysqlclient-dev` or `libmariadb-dev` .